# How do I pull inters out of a string and determine which inter is the highest?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

"Hello I can count to 4, 1 2 3 4."
And it would return that the max number in the string is 4.

I need to pull the integers out of the string and determine which one is the highest.  I've been toying with this for a while, but I can't find a good way to pull the numbers out of the string.  Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Homework eh?

```
import re

for i in re.findall('\d+', "Hello I can count to 4, 1 2 3 4."):
    one_int = int(i)
    print(one_int)
```

To do it without regular expressions, you would have to loop over every character in the string, check if its a digit and remember its position.
One you found one, check if the next digit has exactly last_position+1 and then merge it into the last one, otherwise emit the last number and remember the new one. In the end, emit the remaining remembered digit.

Comment: Yup, I'd post my progress--but it's kind of a mess. :)  Thanks a bunch.  Is there any way to do it with, say, string splicing and testing?

Comment: See my edit, this will be more logic in a loop, but an interesting puzzle

Comment: So I have managed to pull out the integers from the string.  Is there a way to make them into a list and then call max to pull out the biggest one.   Here's what I have so far.
>>for string_test in 'test 123':>>          if string_test.isdigit():
                   >>print (string_test)

Comment: `x = []` and then `x.append(1)` and for max `max(x)` - But you should post your progess, even if its bad :)

Answer (score 1):

One line solution will be like:

```
max(map(int, re.findall('[-+]?\d+',s)))
```

Detaching it:

```
re.findall('[-+]?\d+',s) #Regex to find all integers (including negatives) in your string "s"
map(int, re.findall('[-+]?\d+',s)) #Converting the found strings to list of integers
max(map(int, re.findall('[-+]?\d+',s))) #Returning the max element
```

Comment: this will parse a multi-digit integer into separate numbers. e.g. "Hello 42" into 4 and 2

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on possible separators, and try to map the parts to int. Keep only the ones that can be parsed successfully, and find the max.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Hello I can count to 4, 1 2 3 4."
>>> parts = re.split(r"[ \t,.]", s)
>>> ints = []
>>> for part in parts:
>>>     try:
>>>         ints.append(int(part))
>>>     except ValueError:
>>>         pass
>>> print(max(ints))
4
```

Comment: Is there are way to do i without importing re?  Like, searching the string and testing it for integers.  Thank you by way the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a character is a digit using the `isdigit()` function. Create a list of all the integers in the string and then grab the max from the list.

```
str = "Hello I can count to 4, 1 2 3 4"<br/>
int_list = [int(s) for s in str.split() if s.isdigit()]<br/>
print max(int_list)
```

EDIT:

As TessellatingHeckler points out this doesn't work with punctuation (ex. "4,") as it doesn't pass `isdigit()`.

Comment: This splits on spaces and `4,` is one of the items, and it does not pass `.isdigit()` because of the comma, so it gets ignored. Same with `4.`. It will say the max is 3 for the actual question input.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that would be expected from a student:

```
max = None

num = list('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')

for x in str:
  if x in num:
    if int(x) > max:
      max = int(x)

return max
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional approach to the problem, it also works for numbers greater than 9, but not with negatives:

```
def split_space(string):
    return string.split(" ")

def is_decimal(string):
    return string.isdecimal()


def number_or_none_from_string(string):
    maybe_number = ""
    for character in string:
        if is_decimal(character):
            maybe_number += character
    if maybe_number == "":
        return None
    return int(maybe_number)


def is_not_none(x):
    return x is not None

def max_from_string(string):
    """assumption: all numbers are separated by space"""
    numbers_and_none = map(number_or_none_from_string, split_space(string))
    numbers = filter(is_not_none, numbers_and_none)
    maximum = max(numbers)

    return maximum

def max_from_string_short_version(string):
    """assumption: all numbers are separated by space"""

    return max(filter(is_not_none, map(number_or_none_from_string, split_space(string))))

phrase = "Hello I can count to 4, 1 2 3 4."
print(max_from_string(phrase))
```